# What is the market share of MSCI Barra Equity Model?

Tags: risk-management, factor-models, risk-models, factor-investing

My understanding is that MSCI/Barra's model has a very large market share in funds and banks, but I cannot find out how large is the exact market share.

Is there any data on this, or can someone familiar with this give an estimate? By market share, I mean the (ideally AUM-weighted) fraction of institutions that use this, rather than some other, model. Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "market share" for a model?

Comment: @DStanley The fraction of institutions that use its model (ideally AUM-weighted).

Comment: It's probably a difficult question because you've got hedge funds and prop desks ( at banks )  that might not disclose what they use.

Comment: @markleeds I agree. Just want to get a general sense. Also, what are the major commercial alternatives to MSCI/Barra? (I'm actually not aware of one).

Comment: Hi: It's probably best to get an estimate from the MSCI itself. I forget the names but there used to be some smaller competitors.  I think there was one called Northfield. I'm not sure if it's still around.

Comment: Northfield is still around https://www.northinfo.com/ Also Axioma, APT-Sungard and maybe 1 or 2 others

Comment: @noob2: It's been too long but they all ring a bell. Thanks for recall.

Comment: @noob2 thanks a lot! very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The only reference I know of is from this 2018 JEF paper on "risk model crowding".

> Barra is believed to lead most providers with around a 50% market share.

Bruno, S., Chincarini, L. B., & Ohara, F. (2018). Portfolio construction and crowding. Journal of Empirical Finance, 47, 190-206.

https://ludwigbc.com/pubs/Crowding_JEF_2018